# Prolog: user insert int input and check input according to its size

Tags: prolog, user-input

recently I attend a few seminar talk on AI and logic and started learning prolog. There's a simple c++ program that I wish to create its logic using prolog. the sequence is:

1)user insert integer input (eg: 3).

2) prompt user to enter 3 id which its size must be 5 and integer (eg: 11111,22222,333A)

3)if the input is more or less than 5 or is not integer, it will fail.

So, I have made a few research and tutorial since I just started to learn prolog on my own however I can't seem to find correct answers for my questions. I tried a few times but there's always errors. Please help me. I really appreciate your help. Thank you

p/s: this is not homework. it's just something I would like to learn and try. Thank u.

Comment: Perhaps you can show what you tried? And what do you want to do with the values once you've read them in?

Comment: sorry I forgot to put what I've done. 

gate :-
    writeln('How many people? (terminate with .) or 0 and 0 to stop the program'),
    read(Z). %to get user-input

bas(0,0):- !.

matrix:-
 writeln('Please insert your matric card ID (terminate with .)');
 read(X),
    bas(X). %this one is the id set according to user-input

isDigit(X) :-    ( number(X),
                   X >= 0,
                   X =< 5
                  ); 
  -> true
  ; writeln('[0-5] AND Number'),
  fail).

bas(X):-
    Z is X,
    format('You may come in', [X,Z]),
    gate.

but I got error coz it seems incomplete

Comment: Please do not add code in comments. Please edit your question and put it there, properly formatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's really such simple ?

```
'prompt user'(A,B,C) :- maplist('size must be 5 and integer', [A,B,C]).
'size must be 5 and integer'(N) :- read(N), integer(N), N >= 10**4, N < 10**5.

5 ?- 'prompt user'(A,B,C).
|: 1111.
false.

6 ?- 'prompt user'(A,B,C).
|: 11111.
|: 21222.
|: 99999.
A = 11111,
B = 21222,
C = 99999.
```

Comment: okay I understand. so basically user need to enter 3 id based on A,B and C right? however what if user set the number himself? like if user enter 2, then prolog prompt to enter 2 id, if user enter 5 then he need to enter 5 id.